# Monitoring of a Rake Task and Controling it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I would like to get the status of a Rake Task into my backoffice(That means Running or not running).

And I also would like to start the rake task if it is not running. Otherwise I want to quit it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this part of a gist: https://gist.github.com/1003601#file_delayed_delta.sh

Basically, I save the PID of the rake task to PIDFILE, then use monit to see if it is running.

https://gist.github.com/1003601#file_monitrc

You could also have a cronjob that runs a system command like `ps -ef | grep my_rake_task` and see if anything turns up. This may or may not require less effort.

Comment: Interesting approach :-)
Thanks for the tips ;)